# Different css classes with same property but different values

Tags: css

I have 2 css classes that hold the background-color property. One class is for general elements and the other is for selected elements. I put the selected_element class on the element according to data i have in my model.
This is the css:

```
.selected_obj {
    background-color: #00EE76
}

.general_obj{
    /* Othe CSS Properties */
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
```

This is my JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${myModel.myCollection}" var="obj">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${obj.id == myModel.selectedObj.id}">
                <div class="selected_obj general_obj">
                    <span>${obj.name}</span>
                </div>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <div class="general_obj">
                    <span>${obj.name}</span>
                </div>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
```

When i view the generated HTML, i can see the selected_obj class on the correct elements but the value is overriden by the backgroung-color property value of the general_obj class. How is the correct value selected by the brouwser and how can i overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried changing `class="selected_obj general_obj"` to `class="general_obj selected_obj "` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two conflicting rules with the same specificity are to be applied, the latter one wins. ) In your case `.general_obj` background-color rule wins (= is actually applied), because it goes after the `.specific_obj` rule in CSS file.

This - `class="general_obj selected_obj"` - change in HTML will do nothing to fix the problem, as both classes will still have the same specificity.

One obvious approach to fix this problem is using `!important`:

```
.selected_obj {
    background-color: #00EE76 !important;
}
```

... as styles specified with `!important` will override the styles that otherwise should be applied (by following the general CSS cascading rules).

That goes well as a quick fix, but I'd actually strongly suggest against it (the reasons are described in [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) quite well; CSS-Tricks also have [a mighty word](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) on that topic).

Instead you may either...

- make a specific multi-class rule for such cases, like this:

  `.selected_obj, .selected_obj.generic_obj {
      background-color: #00EE76;
  }`
- (strongly suggested) fix the CSS file so that rules for generic classes are described first and rules for specific classes follow them.

Actually, it's a great rule of thumb: deal with all the generic things first, then work with specialties. )

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
.selected_obj {
    background-color: #00EE76 !important;
}
```

? Notice also semicolon (;) at end. Missing semicolon can produce errors.

Comment: Add another line after background-color and you have not for everybody easy to find error.

Comment: using `!important` in general is not recommended, see e.g. the link in @raina77ow's answer